# How can I bring $\sin(x)$ to the following form?

Tags: trigonometry

What steps do we take for the following?

> $$\sin x = \frac{{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}$$

Comment: Hint: Do you know an identity for $1 + \tan^2\theta$?  Use that, and then write the results in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin x = 2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2} = 2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\frac{x}{2}} = 2\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\frac{x}{2}}\cos^2\frac{x}{2} = \frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}} = \frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}+\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}} = \frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Replace $\tan(y)$ by $\frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}$. Multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos^2(y)$. Simplify.

I am sure that you can take fom here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x/2$, then $$\frac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^2 y} = 2\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}\frac{1}{\sec^2 y} = 2\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}\cos^2 y=2\sin(y)\cos(y)=\sin(2y)=\sin x,$$ as required.